# Is there a name for this Registry-Slot-Updaters pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I noticed a pattern in my code. It applies to situations where things can be selected. It revolves around classes which I call (and in code often suffix with) Registry, Slot and Updater.

### Registry

This class is pretty much a combination of what is known as [the registry pattern](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html): (*"A well-known object that other objects can use to find common objects and services."*) and some filter methods.
These are supposed to be *the list of all [Type]s*. They always use a collection internally, but the methods they have is determined by what other classes want from them. That might be simple wrappers for the collection class  or domain specific, named filter methods. Events - for example when an item is removed - are added pragmatically when needed.

```
public class ProductRegistry
{
    private readonly List<Product> _products = new List<Product>();

    public void Add(Product product)
    {
        _products.Add(Product product)
    }

    public List<Product> GetAllProductsOnSale()
    {
        // domain specific filtering...
    }
}
```

### Slot

Named "Slot" because it can hold an object. In most cases, an object being held here means it is the currently selected object. Contrary to Registry and Updaters, the code for this is always the same except for the type of what is being selected. I could turn this into a generic class, but I only came to think of that while writing this question - and it's not like that would change how this pattern works.

```
public class ProductSlot
{
    public event Action WhenProductHasBeenChanged;

    public Product Product{get; private set;}

    public void Set(Product product)
    {
        Product = product;
        if(WhenProductHasBeenChanged!=null) WhenProductHasBeenChanged();
    }
}
```

### Updaters

These update the registry and slot. How they achieve that varies wildly, so example code wouldn't make sense here.
However, to give an example of what they do, a `ProductUpdater` might supervise the process of downloading a string from a web address, parsing it into `Products` and then add those to the `ProductRegistry`.
One thing I did repeatedly was registering an Updater to the change event of a slot for a different thing. For example, a `ContractSlotUpdater` listens to changes in a `CustomerSlot`, so it can update the `ContractSlot` with the `Contract` which corresponds to the new `Customer`.

### Additional notes

I added the C# tag because that is the language - and thus the language features - that I am currently using. I see no problem transferring this concept to other languages as long as they have the necessary features.

### The question

If this is not a good thing to do, please tell me why.
Otherwise, I would like to know what to call it.

Comment: It sounds like an updater is an arbitrary callback. As for slots, can you go into some detail about how they are useful? What's the benefit of having them be mutable?

Comment: The updaters are indeed so arbitrary that I was unsure whether to add them - but without them, nothing would happen in Registry and Slot. The Slot is there for exactly the 3 things that its public members do; **provide the currently selected object**, **set the currently selected object** and **allow listening to when the currently selected object changes**. I'm a bit confused about the mutable question though. Whatever is in the slot is the current selection. If that's immutable, I wouldn't be able to change the selection.

Comment: I would say remove updaters since a delegate is all that you need. I think it is a problem that the slot is mutable because it stores two pieces of independent mutable state, the current object, and the delegates that respond to changes. 3 responsibilities is a sign that slot has too many concerns, but the bigger problem is that it holds two independently changing mutable values that can get out of sync.

Comment: Well, you asked how they are useful, so I listed what it's public members are there for. If you are thinking SRP, I would say this class's one responsibility is to manage the currently selected object. Tbh, every class having only one public member is the most extreme interpretation of SRP I have ever heard.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that. I'm also not an SRP zealot by any means. My issue is that you can write `var slot = new ProductSlot(p1); slot.WhenProductHasBeenChanged += () => {...}; slot.SetProduct(p2); slot.WhenProductHasBeenChanged += () => {...};`. That seems weird to me.

Comment: I actually think we must have a misunderstanding somewhere, because I don't know how they would get out of sync either. If the current object is changed, the event needs to fire. That already happens in the class and no outside code can change that. If I split the class up into event and current object, I will always need to call the event separately after setting the selection. _Then_ they can - or rather definitely will - get out of sync if one of those things is forgotten. Does this clear things up a bit? Otherwise, how do you think they get out of sync?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71086/discussion-between-aluan-haddad-and-raphael-schmitz).

Comment: Your question presumes that if it's a good thing to do, then it already has a well-known name.  Your presumption is invalid.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't have to be well-known. And if I can not expect this pattern to be well-known under a certain name anyway, I'm perfectly fine continuing to call it Registry-Slot-Updaters.